# How to Hide keyboard in Xamarin Android after clicking outside Edittext

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard

I am working on **Xamarin(Android)** .Now i want to hide keyboard after clicking outside `Edit Text`.

Thanks in Advance.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);


        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        EditText Etusername= FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.EtUname);
        Etusername.SetHintTextColor(Color.Gray);

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Etusername.WindowToken, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this code to Hide `Keyboard`.

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
         InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
         imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Etusername.WindowToken, 0);
         return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
    }
```

and make sure you have to add this library :

```
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the above code  just now but no change. Still Keyboard is appearing.

Comment: @raji glad to help you.